# How to exit or stop the execution of another python script?

Tags: python-2.7, exit-code

Script 1 has imported Script 2

Script 1 invokes a method on Script 2

If some condition is met, Script 2 must exit and Script 1 must resume.

If this is possible, how do I achieve it and how Script 1 understands Script 2 has exited?

I do aware of return statements, but function is nested and hence 'return' would return to the previous function. I want to stop the entire script (Script2), without affecting Script 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I want to stop the entire script (Script2), without affecting Script 1.* - That is not possible. If the function calls are chained, then return a sentinel value and when the other calling functions see the sentinel, make them also simply return immediately.

Comment: @thefourtheye I do understand but I was just looking for stopping the script instead of returning from function calls. Thanks :)

Comment: Ya, that is not possible.